# Using sed instead of rev

Tags: shell, unix, jenkins, sed, reverse

I am running a shell build step in Jenkins (Windows), but, it doesn't seem to recognize the `rev` command. The command I am trying to run is:

```
awk '/Connections/||/Endpoint/||/connections/||/endpoint/||/EndPointURI/ {print $config}' "$config" | rev | cut -c 8- | rev  >temp11
```

I have used `sed '/\n!G;s/\(.\)\(.*\n\)/&\2\1/;//D;s/.//'` to replace each instance of `rev`.

I have the following:

```
awk '/Connections/||/Endpoint/||/connections/||/endpoint/||/EndPointURI/ {print $config}' "$config" | sed '/\n!G;s/\(.\)\(.*\n\)/&\2\1/;//D;s/.//' | cut -c 8- | sed '/\n!G;s/\(.\)\(.*\n\)/&\2\1/;//D;s/.//'  >temp11
```

Using this method, I get the following error in the Jenkins output:

```
+ awk '/Connections/||/Endpoint/||/connections/||/endpoint/||/EndPointURI/ {print $config}' 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins/workspace/DeploymentFiles/BUILD.xml'
+ sed '/\n!G;s/\(.\)\(.*\n\)/&\2\1/;//D;s/.//'
+ cut -c 8-
sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unknown command: `\'
+ sed '/\n!G;s/\(.\)\(.*\n\)/&\2\1/;//D;s/.//'
sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unknown command: `\'
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Not sure how to fix this or make it work.

---

Full script:

```
touch "${JENKINS_HOME}"/workspace/DeploymentFiles/UAT.properties
config=${JENKINS_HOME}/workspace/DeploymentFiles/BUILD.xml
properties=${JENKINS_HOME}/workspace/DeploymentFiles/UAT.properties
a='tibco.clientVar.'
awk '/Connections/||/Endpoint/||/connections/||/endpoint/||/EndPointURI/ {print $config}' "$config" | sed '/\n!G;s/\(.\)\(.*\n\)/&\2\1/;//D;s/.//' | cut -c 8- | sed '/\n!G;s/\(.\)\(.*\n\)/&\2\1/;//D;s/.//'  >temp11
awk '/Connections/||/Endpoint/||/connections/||/endpoint/||/EndPointURI/ {getline; print $config}' "$config" |sed '/\n!G;s/\(.\)\(.*\n\)/&\2\1/;//D;s/.//' | cut -c 9- | sed '/\n!G;s/\(.\)\(.*\n\)/&\2\1/;//D;s/.//'  >temp22
sed -e s/'<name>'//g -i temp11
sed -i '/^$/d' temp11
sed -e s/'<value>'//g -i temp22
sed -i '/^$/d' temp22
while read -r line
do
echo "${a}$line"
done <temp11 >temp3
sed -i '/^$/d' temp3
paste -d'=' temp3 temp22 >  final
sed '/^tibco.clientVar.<checkpoint>/d' final > final.new && mv final.new final
mv final ${properties}
```

Comment: If you could do let us know samples of input and expected output in CODE TAGS in your post, we could help you more on this, please do add the same in your post.

Comment: you are using `{print $config}`, so awk will try to print the field in the `config`-th position (eg, like saying `seq 10 | awk '{print $bla}'`, which prints everything). But you are not setting `config` anywhere. Are you maybe trying to use the shell variable `$config`?

Comment: I have set the config variable before that. I will update the question.

Comment: Check [How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19075671/1983854)